# Calculating Click Through Rate

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data table structured like:

| userID | visitnum | visitpagenum | articleID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user123 | 5 | 21 | home_page |
| user123 | 5 | 22 | article1234 |

where visitnum indicates what visit the event (article visit) occurs in and the visitpagenum indicates the page view number of that visit (increases by 1 for each page view).

I am looking to calculate which articles have the best click through rate. Essentially, I want to capture all the instances where the visit went from the home page to an article.

I've been able to capture one instance of this with:

```
SELECT userID, visitnum, visitpagenum, articleID
FROM table
WHERE userID = 'user123'
ORDER BY visitnum ASC;
```

But, I am not sure how to aggregate all of these instances.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results.  What is the *ratio* that you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . you can easily *count* the instances where someone goes from the home page to an article using `lead()`:

```
select next_article_id, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             lead(article_id) over (partition by userid, visitnum order by visitpagenum) as next_article_id
      from t
     ) t
where article_id = 'home_page'
group by next_article_id
order by count(*) desc;
```

Note:  This will include `NULL` values (when the home page is the last page viewed) and the home page itself (when that is the next page).

I suppose that if you want the *rate*, you can use:

```
select next_article_id, count(*),
       count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as ratio
from . . .
```